# Using Validators with Spring data rest and MVC

Tags: java, validation, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I am using spring-MVC application with spring-data entities. Then in order to expose entities as rest service, I added spring-data-rest module. 
I am trying to validate same entity, using spring-data-rest beforeSaveEventListener Validators.

These entities are also part of MVC and the UI is accessing this entity. 
These validators are not getting invoked when a request comes from MVC application.

How can I have a common validator which can be used by both MVC and spring-data-rest servlets? Moreover, I don't want to use uri redirection from MVC to Rest servlet. Is there any cleaner approach to avoid having two validators one for MVC and other for Rest entity?

Thanks

Comment: is it enough to validate input argument  for controller methods ?

Comment: There would be two areas where inputs would be validated and hence add to the maintenance. I am thinking to have validation at one place for both the MVC service and rest entity.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple, we can reuse the MVC validators in Spring Data Rest events. For example if I want to validate the user password before saving it, I would add the following code to the before save event -

```
@Autowired
PasswordValidator passwordValidator;

@HandleBeforeSave
public void beforeUsersave(User user) {

            PasswordDTO passwordDTO = new PasswordDTO(user.getPassword(), user.getMatchingPassword());
            Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(passwordDTO, "user");

            passwordValidator.validate(passwordDTO, errors);

            if (errors.hasErrors()) {
                throw new RepositoryConstraintViolationException(errors);
            }
}
```

I am using the same PasswordValidator as a MVC validator in my change password call.

Here is my PasswordValidator

```
package org.amnesty.cms.domain.validation;

import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PasswordValidator implements Validator {

    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return PasswordDTO.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    private Pattern pattern;
    private Matcher matcher;
    private static final String passwordRegex = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=\\S+$).{8,50}$";

    public PasswordValidator() {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(passwordRegex);
    }

    public void validate(Object passwordObj, Errors errors) {

        PasswordDTO passwordDTO = (PasswordDTO) passwordObj;
        String password = passwordDTO.getPassword();

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "password", "password", "Password can't be null or empty");

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(password)) {

            if (password.length() < 8) {
                errors.rejectValue("password", "password", "Password length should be at least 8 characters");
            }

            if (password.length() > 50) {
                errors.rejectValue("password", "password", "Password length can't be more than 50 characters");
            }
        }

        if (!errors.hasErrors()) {
            matcher = pattern.matcher(password);
            if (!matcher.matches()) {
                errors.rejectValue("password", "password", "Invalid password. A valid password contains at least " +
                        "one digit, one lowercase character, one uppercase character and no whitespace");
            }
        }

        if (!errors.hasErrors() && !password.equals(passwordDTO.getMatchingPassword())) {
            errors.rejectValue("matchingPassword", "matchingPassword", "Matching password is different from password");
        }
    }
}
```